# How to show a loader in node js application

Tags: node.js, bash, spinner

I am developing a node js application. In my application, I am calling the script file from node js app.

In that script file, I am creating a HDI cluster in azure.

I want to show a spinner till the script completes the creation of HDI cluster and hide the spinner after script execution.

How can I show using Node js application? Provide me an example?

index.js

```
<div class="container">
  <fieldset>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <h4>Create Cluster</h4><br><br>
      <label for="name"> Name:  </label>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="Enter a name" required><br><br>          
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Create">
    </form>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="load"></div>
</div>
```

server.js

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');

    var child = exec('bash sample.sh');

  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    logger.info(data)
  });

  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    logger.error(data);
  });

  child.on('close', function(code) {
    logger.info('Script exit code: ' + code);
  });
})
```

sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# -e: immediately exit if any command has a non-zero exit status
# -o: prevents errors in a pipeline from being masked
# IFS new value is less likely to cause confusing bugs when looping arrays or arguments (e.g. $@)

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 -i <subscriptionId> -g <resourceGroupName> -n <deploymentName> -l <resourceGroupLocation>" 1>&2; exit 1; }

declare subscriptionId=""
declare resourceGroupName=""
declare deploymentName=""
declare resourceGroupLocation=""

# Initialize parameters specified from command line
while getopts ":i:g:n:l:" arg; do
    case "${arg}" in
        i)
            subscriptionId=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        g)
            resourceGroupName=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        n)
            deploymentName=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        l)
            resourceGroupLocation=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        h)
            echo "This message"
        esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

#Prompt for parameters is some required parameters are missing
if [[ -z "$subscriptionId" ]]; then
    echo "Your subscription ID can be looked up with the CLI using: az account show --out json "
    echo "Enter your subscription ID:"
    read subscriptionId
    [[ "${subscriptionId:?}" ]]
fi

if [[ -z "$resourceGroupName" ]]; then
    echo "This script will look for an existing resource group, otherwise a new one will be created "
    echo "You can create new resource groups with the CLI using: az group create "
    echo "Enter a resource group name"
    read resourceGroupName
    [[ "${resourceGroupName:?}" ]]
fi

if [[ -z "$deploymentName" ]]; then
    echo "Enter a name for this deployment:"
    read deploymentName
fi

if [[ -z "$resourceGroupLocation" ]]; then
    echo "If creating a *new* resource group, you need to set a location "
    echo "You can lookup locations with the CLI using: az account list-locations "

    echo "Enter resource group location:"
    read resourceGroupLocation
fi

#templateFile Path - template file to be used
templateFilePath="template.json"

if [ ! -f "$templateFilePath" ]; then
    echo "$templateFilePath not found"
    exit 1
fi

#parameter file path
parametersFilePath="parameters.json"

if [ ! -f "$parametersFilePath" ]; then
    echo "$parametersFilePath not found"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$subscriptionId" ] || [ -z "$resourceGroupName" ] || [ -z "$deploymentName" ]; then
    echo "Either one of subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, deploymentName is empty"
    usage
fi

#login to azure using your credentials
az account show 1> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ];
then
    az login
fi

#set the default subscription id
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

set +e

#Check for existing RG
az group show $resourceGroupName 1> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Resource group with name" $resourceGroupName "could not be found. Creating new resource group.."
    set -e
    (
        set -x
        az group create --name $resourceGroupName --location $resourceGroupLocation 1> /dev/null
    )
    else
    echo "Using existing resource group..."
fi

#Start deployment
echo "Starting deployment..."
(
    set -x
    az group deployment create --name "$deploymentName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --template-file "$templateFilePath" --parameters "@${parametersFilePath}"
)

if [ $?  == 0 ];
 then
    echo "Template has been successfully deployed"
fi
```

Comment: can you edit question with your code snippet?

Comment: Also please mention how are you calling your node code from your UI ?

Comment: @Harish I have updated the question.

Comment: @damitj07 I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is similar to a long async processing task which will run on server side. This process will be initiated by your user or frontend code.

There are a couple of ways to handle such scenarios based on the Average expected time it will take to complete the task. Let's distinguish them broadly as :

**1. Operation time less than 3 seconds (<= 3000ms)**

In this case, you since you know the time taken for your operation which can be anything like reading a file or create cluster or setup mongo database, etc. So you can have a simple XHR or AJAX call made from your front-end code to the node server.

```
//index.html

<fieldset>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" onSubmit="makeRequest()" method="post">
        <h4>Create Cluster</h4><br><br>
        <label for="name"> Name:  </label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="Enter a name" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Create" onclick="makeRequest()">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="myLoader"></div>
</div>

<script>
    // I have missed some code for sake of breviety
    var makeRequest = function() {
        //get the value entered by the user in name input box
        var data = {name: 'xyz'};
        data.name = document.getElementsByName('name').value;

        //Since your request is about to begin 
        //after user has clicked on action button
        //Show loader
        document.getElementById("myLoader").style.opacity = 1;
        //Loader is visible to user

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ...
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                //Since your request is complete
                //Hide loader
                document.getElementById("myLoader").style.opacity = 0;
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        });

        xhr.open("POST", "http://mynodeserver/api/perfromOperation");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(inputDataForserver);
    }
</script>
```

On other hand server side will handle the request perform from the operation and return a response within no more than 3 Seconds.

```
       //Server.js
       //This will load our index.html on users browser
        app.post('/', function(req, res) {
           res.render('index');
         });
        //OR 
        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
        });

        //This endpoint will be called by user action 
        app.post('/api/perfromOperation', function(req, res) {
          //The data sent from UI is found in req.body
          //Make sure the data path is as needed...
          var name = req.body.name;
          var child = exec('bash sample.sh -n '+name);
          ...
          ...
          child.on('close', function(code) {
            logger.info('Script exit code: ' + code);
            res.json({ "code": code });
          });

        });
```

**2. Operation time more than 3 seconds (=> 3000ms)**

This case will call for you to have a more complex flow where you can make a call to the server from front-end which will trigger the long process of creating the Azure cluster.

This will create a record in your temporary database about the operation with details like - [operationId: #1] [Status: 'In_Progress']
And you will then update this record after the operation with id #1 has completed or errored out.

Again this will call for you to make another call from your front-end to check the status.

*note *: The time is used as a reference and may vary as per your own specification and preferences.*

---

I hope this helps, and if you want to trigger the operation of cluster creation on page load you can do that as well by making the XHR call as mentioned before on document onLoad event.

Comment: How to pass the name value to sample.sh as an argument.

Comment: Same way as you do it in CLI,  e.g : A cat command 
exec("cat '/route/to/file_a' '/route/to/file_b'") @karan

Comment: I want to pass the name entered in Node UI passed to this line "var child = exec('bash sample.sh');"

Comment: @karan I have updated the code a bit to give you a brief idea of how u can achieve that. you may need to change few things as per your requirements. HTH 
Please accept the answer if it helped you .